# CLR Garbage Collection For Local variables in .Net

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr, static-methods, shared

I have a following code segment in one my classes. Please note that this is a static method. What I would like to know is that when I create a new StringBuilder object, what happens to the old one? Does it get garbage collected?

Thanks,
Prayag

```
Public Shared Function CleanUpSql(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(s.Trim())
    RemoveBrackets(sb)
    FixWhiteSpace(sb)
    TrimSemicolon(sb)
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: It gets Garbage collected! If you want to know when and how, read books, MSDN, articles, blogs.

Comment: GC happens at the GC algorithm's convenience. Objects are marked for GC when they go out of scope and have no references to them anymore.

Comment: @Jeroen I have found GC can collect objects in the current scope, as long as they are not used any more. Hence the need for [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

At some point after execution leaves your `CleanUpSql` method, and thereby leaves the scope in which `sb` is defined, the `StringBuilder` referenced by `sb` will be garbage collected. You don't know exactly when this collection will happen (and you probably don't care).

An object is subject to garbage collection when no in-scope variables reference it.

You can *request* that collection happen immediately with [`System.GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) (which, in, the current implementation of the CLR, performs garbage collection immediately). I'd suggest that you *not* do this, however - manual garbage collection manipulation is rarely necessary.

If you're interested in more detail, [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx).

Comment: Even though the method is static and used over and over many times it would discard old sb object or do I need to specifically remove it? Thanks for you answer..

Comment: @Prayag: It will get garbage collected automatically - you don't need to do anything. The *variable* `sb` isn't static. If it were, that'd be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it does, sometime after the sub exists as the reference to the object exist on the call stack. But its collected whenever the CLR feels the need, not necessarily when you make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating sb on stack, so as soon as call to CleanUpSql quits sb is not accessible and would be garbage collected. You even don't need to make another call.

Comment: More precisely, i think you mean "sb is not accessible and would be **eligible** for garbage collection".